# Braces as an ES6 function declaration statement?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuex

Found this in a tutorial I was going over. 
It's ES6.

I'm just not sure whats exactly going on. Namely , the way the function(?) is being declared with the array. Where is the colon that declares it as a function?

```
[types.ADD_TO_CART] (state, { id })
```

Also what's up with the brackets in the parameter declaration?

```
(state, { id })
```

Here's the tutorial.

https://medium.com/@connorleech/build-a-shopping-cart-with-vue-2-and-vuex-5d58b93c513f

```
[types.ADD_TO_CART] (state, { id }) {
  const record = state.added.find(p => p.id === id)
  if (!record) {
    state.added.push({
      id,
      quantity: 1
    })
  } else {
    record.quantity++
  }
}
```

Comment: think of it like `with(obj)`, but without the crap and on a short-listed dynamic object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define a method on a class without using `:`:

```js
class Example {
  method() {
    console.log('here')
  }
}

new Example().method()
```

With ES6 computed property names, you can make the name of that method be dynamic:

```js
const name = 'method'
class Example {
  [name]() {
    console.log('here');
  }
}

new Example()[name]()
```

As far as the `({ id })` part, the `id` represents an extracted property from the arguments of that dynamic method using destructuring:

```
// this
[types.ADD_TO_CART](state, obj) => {
   let id = obj.id;
}

// can be abbreviated to this
[types.ADD_TO_CART](state, { id }) => {

}
```

For example:

```js
const name = 'method'
class Example {
  [name]({
    id
  }) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}

new Example()[name]({
  id: 'example'
})
```

Further resources: [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: s/can define/must define/ :-)

Comment: @Bergi true, fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

With ES2015, you can get two new features for object literals:

```
// Computed object properties

const foo = 'bar'
const myObj = {
    [foo]: 'hello world'
}

// Shorthand method definitions:

const mySecondObj = {
    myMethod () {
        // code...
    }
}
```

The code in the example seems to combine both.

---

Also, ES2015 gives you [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), which is used for the parameter – thus the curly brackets.

---

[Check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for more details on the new syntax features.